# Graph User id property returning blank string

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've got a php web app (hosted on Azure) using the microsoft/microsoft-graph SDK for one of my authentication providers.

I am able to get a token and pull some of the user properties, but the 'id' value seems to be returning a blank string:

```
$me = $provider->get("me", $token);

printf('<br>Hello %s!', $me['displayName']);
printf('<br>First Name: %s', $me['givenName']);
printf('<br>Last Name: %s', $me['surname']);
printf('<br>ID: %s', $me['id']);   // returns nothing
printf('<br>Email: %s', $me['userPrincipalName']);
printf('<br>Country: %s', $me['country']);
printf('<br>Postal Code: %s', $me['postalCode']);
```

According to the [User reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user), I should be able to get the user ID value as a string.

I am also using `thenetworg/oauth2-azure` as part of the project and the following does return a GUID. Is it the same ID that I'm looking for? The unique user ID from Graph? Or is it a different ID?

```
printf('<br>ID: %s', $resourceOwner->getId());
```

Ideally, I'd like to get the ID value directly from Graph like all the other properties. Is there something I'm missing that I need to do special for the ID property? (well, obviously...) Is the issue with Graph, with the php library, or something else?

Thanks for your assistance.

---

[Update]

OK, so backing up a step: I've got two pages:

Page 1 has links to a number of authentication options. 
Page 2 is a redirect from one of those options - the Microsoft Work and School option.

Page 1 now uses the following to create the link:

```
$mscallbackUrl = $urlcore . '/ms-callback.php';
$provider = new TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure([
    'clientId'      => $msAppId,
    'clentSecret'   => $msAppSecret,
    'redirectUri'   => $mscallbackUrl
]);
$provider->urlAPI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
$provider->resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";

$authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
```

Page 2 uses the exact same code above to set up $provider then uses the following to connect to Graph:

```
$token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
    'code' => $_GET['code']
]);

try {
    $graph = new \Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($token->getToken());
    $me = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me")
        ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
        ->execute();

    printf('<br>Hello %s!', $me->getDisplayName());
    printf('<br>ID: %s', $me->id);
```

This code is failing on `$me = $graph->createRequest`
One reference I found said it could be failing because of an issue with the token.

Comment: What is the failure message you're getting? Without the error, it's pretty hard to tell what might be going on.

Comment: Right now I'm getting a 500 internal server error. I haven't been able to narrow it down past that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few things that may be causing the confusion. By default, the `oauth2-azure` library authenticates for the AAD Graph resource (https://graph.windows.net) instead of the Microsoft Graph resource (https://graph.microsoft.com), so you will want to verify that you request an access token for the correct resource.

Secondly, AAD Graph does not return an `id` field so this will return null. I believe the correlated equivalent field to MS Graph is `oid`.

Third, you are using the `oauth2-azure` library to access AAD Graph instead of the `microsoft-graph` library for Microsoft Graph. Once you get your access token, you can pass that into a new Graph instance like so:

```
$graph = new \Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token->getToken());
$me = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me")
    ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
    ->execute();

echo $me->id;
```

Comment: Yep, was definitely confused about there being 2 different 'graphs'.